# avoiding to android tween animation changes position

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I'm creating an animation to increase the size of TextView. this is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromXScale="0.5"
android:toXScale="2.5"
android:fromYScale="0.5"
android:toYScale="2.5"
android:duration="4000" />
```

and this is my Java file:

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.answeranim);
txtanswer.startAnimation(anim);
```

My problem is that my TextViewer goes to the screen center and starts the animation. I want my TextViewer to increase his size from position that I set already. In fact I want the Animation to just increase the TextViewer size not change it's position. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this may give you some directions, you probably will have to tweak the valeus a bit:

```
TextView text = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.idTesteText);
    ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f, 
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    anim.setDuration(700);
    text.startAnimation(anim);
```

If you set pivotX and pivotY half of the width and height it will scale from center if you need that.

You can check de documentation here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation.html